# rvm - can I make a version of ruby installed via rvm the system default (I thought it would be)?

Tags: ruby, rvm, passenger

I always have a hard time with rvm so sorry if this has been answered - I have to work with rvm infrequently so some of the ideas don't fully set in.

On my server (a fresh droplet at Digital Ocean) i installed rvm as the `deploy` user, via:

```
$\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
$ source /home/deploy/.rvm/scripts/rvm
$rvm install 1.9.3-p392
$rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

If I login as root, I can't see this ruby. Can I make this the system ruby or did I make a mistake? For example, I tried installing the nginx component of passenger via:

```
root$ passenger-install-nginx-module
```

but get

```
root$ passenger-install-nginx-module: command not found
```

and

```
root$ which ruby # nothing
```

Am I supposed to just add the add the path of /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ as an environment variable (I doubt that)? Or have I totally messed this up (which is ok since we don't have anything on droplet)? Is this the recommended way to manage rubies?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

you must load your environtment into folder before.
Run this command in terminal:

```
       $ rvm use 1.9.3
```

Then "ruby -v" must work.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the guide to *multi user install* on this page: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ (Install with `sudo`)

Comment: thx, ideally hoping to get this working in single-user mode but will read through whether single-user makes more sense